# Skilled Migrant - AUS

Tags: working-visas, australia

I understand about ACS and IELTS/PTE steps to be followed before applying for Visa (189- Skilled Migrant).

I have below mentioned questions - [1]All the sites about Australia Migration mention IELTS. Not sure if PTE is accepted and what is the minimum PTE score required for this. I understand for IELTS it is 7 points in each section.

[2] Police clearance requirements - What kind of docs are expected to be submitted to fulfill this requirement.

[3] Medical tests - What medical tests are expected to be performed.

Comment: The police and medical stuff will depend on your citizenship and country of residence - what are those?

Comment: PTE requirements are [here](https://www.border.gov.au/Lega/Lega/Form/Immi-FAQs/aelt)

Answer (score 2):

According to the expanded information for the Australia Skilled Independent visa (subclass 189)

1. [English language ability](https://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa-1/189-?modal=/Visas/supporting/Pages/skilled/english-language-ability.aspx)

> You can use one test result from any of the following English language test providers:
>   [International English Language Testing System (IELTS)](http://www.ielts.org/)
>   [Occupational English Test (OET)](http://www.occupationalenglishtest.org/)
>   [Test of English as a Foreign Language internet-Based Test (TOEFL iBT)](http://www.ets.org/toefl/ibt/about)
>   [Pearson Test of English (PTE) Academic)](http://pearsonpte.com/testme)
>   [Cambridge Advanced English (CAE)](http://www.cambridgeenglish.org/exams/advanced/results/)

2. [Character](https://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa/Char)

> If you are applying for temporary or permanent migration
>   For the Australian Government to determine whether you are of good character, you might be asked to provide police certificates for each country you have lived in for 12 months or more, over the last 10 years (calculated immediately before the time the visa application is lodged), since turning 16 years of age.
>
> You must declare all recorded offences to us. If you do not declare an offence and we become aware of this it might have a negative impact on your application.
>
> **How do I obtain a police certificate?**
>   For instructions on obtaining a certificate from an overseas government or law enforcement authority, refer to the [relevant country information](https://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa/Char).

3. [Health examinations](https://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa/Heal/meeting-the-health-requirement/health-examinations#)

> What you need to do to meet the health requirement will depend on your personal circumstances and the visa that you have applied for. All permanent provisional and certain temporary visa applicants are required to undergo health examinations as part of the visa application process to determine if they meet the health requirement.
>
> If you fail to meet the health requirement your visa may be refused, however this will depend on the visa subclass you have applied for. Some visa subclasses allow a health waiver to be exercised in certain circumstances.
>
> The [table below outlines health examinations](https://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa/Heal/meeting-the-health-requirement/health-examinations#)  that you and members of your family unit (if applying to migrate with you to Australia) will generally be required to undertake.